# Creating null pointers from c++11 template parameter pack

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, c++11

I'm doing some metaprogramming and right now I need to test if a member function of a given type is callable with a given set of arguments, so I'm doing something like the following (which is heavily simplified by removing everything not important for this particular problem of course):

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
struct argument_tester {
    struct base: public T { 
        using T::my_member; 
        no my_member(...){}
    };
    typedef decltype(static_cast<base*>(0)->my_member(*static_cast<Args*...>(0))) type;
    //verify return type
};
```

Of course it doesn't work with `*static_cast<Args*...>(0)`, so my question is whether there is any way to unpack a parameter pack as dereferenced null pointers or if this is a case where I have to specialize for each number of arguments. And of course if there is a way how I would do that? I'm using `gcc 4.6` in case that makes a difference for what's possible and what isn't.

Comment: Do you know of `std::declval`?

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes: I didn't, but what difference would that make for this situation

Comment: There is a bug, I think, in this code, `base` is unused, and I think it was meant to be used in place of `T` in `static_cast<T*>(0)`.

Comment: @Grizzly: not much, but you wouldn't need to use static casts and dereference null pointers. Just making people aware of the new tools :)

Comment: Using `std::declval` makes the code substantially cleaner (for one) and enables you to specify `T&` as an argument. At the moment, if one of the parametric argument it `T&`, then `T&*` will fail...

Comment: while I don't think it makes that much of a difference in terms of code cleansiness, I had forgotten about the pointer to reference problem, so thanks for thhe heads up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `...` unpack "operator" can be placed outside the expression, in which case the expression is expanded.

The solution would thus be, I think, `(*static_cast<Args*>(0))...`.

**EDIT**: Following R. Martinho Fernandes' hint

```
typedef decltype(std::declval<base>().my_member(std::declval<Args>()...)) type;
```